# Does ngrx selectors gets called once on initial load

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-entity

It it normal for a ngrx selector to have an emitted value despite no action is dispatched at all?

This console.log runs here even if no actions are dispatched in my app

```js
this.bookmarks$ = this.store.pipe(
  select(fromBookmarks.selectBookmarks),
  tap(_ => console.log('fetch bookmarks'))
);
```

Would it be okay to `skip(1)` the first emission or it's kinda hacky.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the selectors and actions independent: selectors query the state, and reducers listen to actions in order to update the state. So:

- There is always a state, a initial state when app starts ==> selector will always return a value
- Actions will not always make changes to state, they can be ignored by reducers.

Comment: there's that initial state that i've been thinking about but i asked just to be sure. Thanks